# CakePHP Access database table

Tags: cakephp

Suppose a table name of mysql database is '`admin`' and controller name is '`userscontroller`' and model name is '`user`'.

How can I access the data from the table '`admin`' in **cakephp**? 
Please explain with code.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the best solution but What I would do is make a new Model called 'Admin' specifically for that table, then in the UserController Call it, example:

In the UserController

```
 $this->loadModel('Admin');
 $this->Admin->find('all');
```

In the Admin Model

```
 $useTable = 'admin';
```

Comment: if the model is User he just needs to put `$useTable = 'admin';` in his `User` model file

Comment: Correct, but if the User model is only accessing the 'admin' table, the model should be named Admin. ( Makes things a lot easier in the long run )